# Android Google Login Auth NeedPermission issue

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin

I'm adding the google login in my application now. but i got the token which came from this scope `scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN`, but server can not get user's email by that token. so I added my scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" with one space. but i only get a system error. like this

> 06-19 15:26:33.444  25229-25460/ W/System.err﹕
>   com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException:
>   NeedPermission 06-19 15:26:33.445  25229-25460/
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
>   06-19 15:26:33.447  25229-25460/ W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)

I totally don't understand what kind of permission i need. 
and this is also my code.

```
AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask() {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        final String CLIENT_ID = "abc123.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(new String[]{
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
        });
        try {
            String scopes = String.format("oauth2:server:client_id:%s:api_scope:%s", CLIENT_ID , TextUtils.join(" ", SCOPES));
            String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient), scopes);
            userInfo = new GoogleUserInfo(email, finalPersonPhotoUrl, currentPerson.getId(), token, currentPerson.getDisplayName());`enter code here`
        }
        catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            // This error is recoverable, so we could fix this
            // by displaying the intent to the user.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
        }
    };
task.execute((Void) null);
```

How can i have the token that can get a user infomation with email ? ? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried many ways but I can't, so I got email like

```
String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(GoogleApiClient);
```

and other informations for user, you can get it all by calling Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson